# Pass Dropdown value inside html.beginform to ajax action call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am really new in javascript and ajax. My problem is that I am trying to pass the value selected from a dropdown list to an ajax call of a method in order to display a partial view.

This is my Index view:

```
@ModelType FCSWebMVC.Models.SubmitBaselineSelectLists
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Status Area"
End Code
<h4>@ViewData("Title")</h4>
<br />

<div>
@Using (Html.BeginForm("GetBaseline", "StatusArea"))
@Html.Label("Select Baseline:")
@Html.DropDownList("cmbBaselineType", Model.m_SelectListBaseline)@<br />@<br />
@<input type="button" value="Select!" />
End Using
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cmbBaselineType").onchange(function () {
        var baseline = $('#cmbBaselineType').val();
        $("#viewPlaceHolder").load("@Url.Action("StatusList", "StatusArea")", { Bid: baseline },
            function (response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    alert("An error occurred while loading the results.");
                }
            });
    });
});
</script>

<div id="viewPlaceHolder"></div>
```

I am not sure how to get the value of the item selected in the dropdown list and pass it to action method StatusList in my controller.

This is my StatusList action method:

```
'action to display current features based on baseline
    Public Function StatusList(ByVal search As String, ByVal Bid As Integer) As ActionResult
        Return PartialView("_StatusList", m_StatusRepository.GetStatusList(Bid, search))
    End Function
```

Comment: is your `onchange` event handler being fired? (use Chrome Dev tools or console.log to find out)  `@Html.DropDownList()` will set the **name** attribute of the dropdown list to "cmbBaselineType", but won't set the **ID** attribute, which means your jQuery may not be selecting anything, since your selector is based on ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cmbBaselineType").on('change', function () {
        var baseline = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           path: 'StatusList',
           data: { search: '', Bid: baseline },
           success: function(result){
             $('#viewPlaceHolder').html(result);
           },
           error: function(){
             //do something
           }
        });
});});</script>
```

P.s @Html.DropDownList() will assign an "id" attribute (despite of comments saying otherwise).